# Add position column based on order by - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this table with the following records:

table1

```
id      ele_id_1    ele_val      ele_id_2       
1       2           123          1  
1       1           abc          1  
1       4           xyz          2  
1       4           456          1  
2       5           22           1
2       4           344          1  
2       3           6            1  
2       2           Test Name    1          
2       1           Hello        1
```

I am trying to add position for each `id` when `ele_id_1` and `ele_id_2` is order by ASC.

Here is the output:

```
id      ele_id_1    ele_val      ele_id_2       position
1       2           123          1              2
1       1           abc          1              1
1       4           xyz          2              4
1       4           456          1              3
2       5           22           1              5
2       4           344          1              4
2       3           6            1              3
2       2           Test Name    1              2
2       1           Hello        1              1
```

I have 34 million rows in table1, so would like to use an efficient way of doing this.

Any idea on how I can add position with values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()` used like this:

```
select row_number() over (partition by id
                          order by ele_id_1, ele_id_2
                         ) as position
```

Oracle can use an index for this, on `(id, ele_id_1, ele_id_2)`.

I should note that for your example data `order by ele_id_1, ele_id_2` and `order by ele_id_2, ele_id_1` produce the same result.  Your question suggests that you want the first.

So, you would get

```
id      ele_id_1    ele_val      ele_id_2       position
1       1           123          2          2
1       1           abc          1          1
1       4           xyz          2          4
1       4           456          1          3
```

Rather than:

```
id      ele_id_1    ele_val      ele_id_2       position
1       1           123          2          3
1       1           abc          1          1
1       4           xyz          2          4
1       4           456          1          2
```

EDIT:

If you want to *update* the data, then `merge` is probably the best approach.

```
MERGE INTO <yourtable> dest
   USING (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by id
                                    order by ele_id_1, ele_id_2
                                   ) as new_position
          from <yourtable> t
         ) src
         ON dest.id = src.id AND
            dest.ele_id_1 = src.ele_id_1 AND
            dest.ele_id_2 = src.ele_id_2          
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET desc.postition = src.new_position;
```

Note that updating all the rows in a table is an expensive operation.  Truncating the table and recreating it might be easier:

```
create table temp_t as 
    select t.*, 
           row_number() over (partition by id
                              order by ele_id_1, ele_id_2
                             ) as new_position
    from t;

truncate table t;

insert into t ( . . . )
    select . . .  -- all columns but position
    from temp_t;
```

However, be very careful if you truncate the table.  Be sure to back it up first!

Comment: @dang . . . This should be the most efficient way to calculate the result on 34 million rows.

Comment: Ok, cool. Should I do a create table as with this extra column? OR run an update query?

Comment: When I'm running the select query with row_number() over (partition by id
                          order by ele_id_1, ele_id_2
                         ) as position, it is taking 441 seconds for the first 50 results. Is there anyway to optimise it?

Comment: Btw, thank you for sharing the merge and create table queries.

Comment: *"it is taking 441 seconds for the first 50 results"* - to calculate the `row_number()` Oracle has to establish all the distinct values of ID and then sort the permutations of ELE_ID_1, ELE_ID_2. Although as Gordon points out Oracle can use an index for this operation it still has to merge all 34m calculated positions with all 34m rows in the table (because the result set includes other column ELE_VAL). So, how long do you think would be reasonable for such a task.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the time taken to render rows in an IDE depends on network traffic and the efficiency of the UI's display code. It doesn't necessarily reflect on the  performance of the driving SQL.